# linked list moving node to the end C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to move a selected element (node) from a linked list to the end of this list.

```
struct* move(struct* list , struct* element)
{

  while(list->next != NULL)
   {
      list = list->next;
   }

  list = element;
  return list;

}
```

First, the struct `element` was part of `list` but I need to move it to the end. However , his doenst seem to be working...

Comment: What if element happens to be the first item on the list ? BTW: `struct move( ...` is a syntax error.

Comment: *None* of the `struct` in this code code are valid C as near as I can see. So right now as best i see i "isn't working" because it isn't even successfully *compiling*.

Comment: `list` and `element` are from the same type. I tried with `list->next` but it doenst work too :(
If `element` happens to be the first item it shouldnt be a problem I think. I just need to move a single element to the end, not looking at his original emplacement

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you please explain what you means when you says that  `struct`is not valid? Actually, the real name of the structure is not `struct`but `poly` I just wanted to give a global definition of my problem, not the special case I'm stuck in.

Comment: @user4135594 `struct poly` isn't even in this code. And `struct * mode(...` isn't valid C, `struct *list` isn't valid C, `struct *element` isn't valid C, etc. Each of those is missing the **tag** (as in `struct sometag *move(struct sometag* arg, ...`). When posting code, take the time to make it an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `list = element;` you actually makes `list` point to `element` which doesn't change your list.

What you want to do is:

```
list->next = element;
element->next = NULL;
```

But you still need to remove `element` from its previous position. A sample of `move()` would be this:

```
struct struct_type * move(struct struct_type * list , struct struct_type * element) {
    while (list->next != NULL) {
        if (list->next == element)
            list->next = list->next->next;

        list = list->next;
    }

    list->next = element;
    element->next = NULL;

    return list;
```

}

As noted in the comments, you have to specify the struct type of the list.
Also note that returning `list` returns the last but one element on your list (which I don't think is the expected behavior).

EDIT: treating first element and returning the top element of the list.

```
struct struct_type * move(struct struct_type * list , struct struct_type * element) {
    struct struct_type *l = list; //keeps reference to the list

    if (l == NULL)
        return l;
    if (l == element)
        list = l->next;

    while (l->next != NULL) {
        if (l->next == element)
            l->next = l->next->next;

        l = l->next;
    }

    l->next = element;
    element->next = NULL;

    return list;    
}
```

Comment: I made a lot of mistakes but with your help guys it's working now.
Thank you very much everybody =) !

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    char name;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *move(struct node *list, struct node *element){
    struct node *head = list;
    struct node *prev = NULL, *curr = head;
    if(list == NULL || list->next == NULL)
        return head;
    while(curr){
        if(curr == element){
            if(curr == head){
                head = curr->next;
            } else {
                prev ->next = curr->next;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
        } else {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
    prev->next = element;
    element->next = NULL;
    return head;
}

void print(struct node *list);

int main(void) {
    struct node a[] = {
        {'A', NULL},
        {'B', NULL},
        {'C', NULL},
        {'D', NULL},
        {'E', NULL}
    }, *head;
    a[0].next = &a[1];
    a[1].next = &a[2];
    a[2].next = &a[3];
    a[3].next = &a[4];

    print(head=a);//A->B->C->D->E
    head = move(head, head);
    print(head);//B->C->D->E->A
    head = move(head, &a[2]);
    print(head);//B->D->E->A->C
    head = move(head, &a[2]);
    print(head);//B->D->E->A->C

    return 0;
}

void print(struct node *list){
    while(list){
        printf("%c", list->name);
        list = list->next;
        if(list)
            printf("->");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```